# Saving and used data in Realm data, Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am writing a travel application.
There are several ViewControllers in the application: Trip -> Day -> Place.

```
    class DayVC: UITableViewController {
    var selectedTrip: NewTrip!
    var days: Results<NewDay>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = selectedTrip.name
        recievedDays()
    }

    func recievedDays() {
        days = self.selectedTrip.days.filter("status = 0")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days.isEmpty ? 0 : days.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellDay = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellDay", for: indexPath) as! CustomDayTVCell
        var day: NewDay!
        day = days[indexPath.row]
        cellDay.dayNameLabel.text = day.name
        cellDay.dayDateLabel.text = day.date
        return cellDay
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let day = days[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDay", sender: day)
    }

    @IBAction func unwindSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        guard let newDayVC = segue.source as? NewDayVC else {return}
        newDayVC.saveDay()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
extension DayVC {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let day = sender as? NewDay {
            if segue.identifier == "showDay" {
                let navigationVc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
                let newDayVC = navigationVc?.topViewController as? NewDayVC
                newDayVC?.currentDay = day
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And there are separate ViewControllers to create a "NewTrip" / "NewDay" / "NewPlace"

```
class NewDayVC: UITableViewController {

    var currentDay: NewDay?
    var selectedTrip: NewTrip?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func saveDay() {
        let newday = NewDay(name: dayName.text!,
                            date: dayDate.text)
        if currentDay != nil {
            try! realm.write {
                currentDay?.name = dayName.text!
                currentDay?.date = dayDate.text!
            }
        } else {
            try! realm.write {
                self.selectedTrip?.days.append(newday)
            }
        }
        print (newday)
    }

    private func setupEditScreen() {
        if currentDay != nil {
            dayName.text = currentDay!.name
            dayDate.text = currentDay!.date
        }
    }
 }
```

Created models look like this:

```
class NewTrip: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var startDate: String?
    @objc dynamic var endDate: String?
    let days = List<NewDay>()
}

class NewDay: Object { 
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: String?
    @objc dynamic var status = 0
}
```

The problem is in saving data when creating a "New Day". He is not saving or I do not see him. What is wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjC97.gif)

> **UPDATE: Found a solution to the problem**

It was:

```
extension DayVC {  
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//        if let day = sender as? NewDay {
//            if segue.identifier == "showDay" {
//                let navigationVc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
//                let newDayVC = navigationVc?.topViewController as? NewDayVC
//                newDayVC?.currentDay = day
//            }
//        }
```

It's now:

```
        if segue.identifier == "showDay" {
            let navigationVc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
            let newDayVC = navigationVc?.topViewController as? NewDayVC
            newDayVC?.selectedTrip = selectedTrip

            guard let day = sender as? NewDay else { return }
            newDayVC?.currentDay = day
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you omitted some relevant code so it's hard to say what the problem is. But in NewDayVC, I would venture to guess that either 1) saveDay is not getting called or 2) selectedTrip is nil

Comment: I'm with @Rob on the `seletedTrip` being nil. When the NewDayVC is instantiated that var is created `var selectedTrip: NewTrip?` but then nothing populates it so this `self.selectedTrip?.days.append(newday)` fails. Along with that, the way in which you're handling optionals is dangerous  and will crash your code. Optionals should be safely unwrapped and assigned default values if nil, or handle situations where they are nil. You should probably set it up where that var is never nil, thus eliminating the need for it to be optional.

Comment: Rob, Jay thanks for answers. Fixed